# Column-Count Css error in Safari for editable content div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `div` element with `contenteditable="true"`. I have given `-webkit-column-count: 2` for making it two column. When I type into the first column and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it jumps to the second column in safari. In Chrome, it is working good.

```
<div class="textarea" contenteditable="true"></div>    

.textarea
{
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  -webkit-column-count:2;
  -webkit-column-gap:25px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Here is the mockup [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5036utf/1/)

Comment: It's definitely an issue... When you keep writing the value you typed on the first column and hit enter it gets pushed to the first column. Also if you fill both columns you get another column. It must have been designed thinking of displaying text rather than writing it on the fly. But Chrome gets it done. Really interesting... Are you trying this with the latest Safari (OS X Mavericks)?

Answer (score 0):

Add `-webkit-column-fill: auto`

http://jsfiddle.net/b5036utf/12/